# robospice, spring-android, how to make oauth REST calls

Tags: spring, oauth, robospice

I have an android app which communicates with server through REST calls. OAuth is used for authentication. Everything plays well, with signpost library and AsyncTasks.

Since AsyncTask has many flaws (memory leaks etc.), I was trying to implement REST calls with
RoboSpice library. RoboSpice is very cool. The only problem (and also a showstopper for me) is
that I can not figure out how does OAuth fit in with RoboSpice.

btw, I'm using robospice with spring-android.

Comment: Did have any luck implementing this?

Comment: yes, I've extended the SpringAndroidSpiceRequest and added the oauth info: requestHeaders.set("Authorization", oauthHeader);

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the maintainers of RS. Personally, I never used OAuth with Spring Android. I only use the REST part os Spring Android.

So, I don't have any idea of what could be missing. Would you mind to give more details on what's blocking you ?

Normally, it should be pretty easy to inject anything into a RS service.

Comment: REST services which I need to access through REST calls are secured with OAuth. I've been doing some more reading and I think this is not a robospice issue since robospice is trying to be protocol-agnostic.